# SetTimeout context binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to set a timeout to hide a bootstrap modal, but even with what I thought was proper context binding, I couldn't get the modal to hide. I did however get it to work when wrapped in a function, and since I have use the `bind` command quite often with success, I am wondering where I went wrong.

```
function Foo() {
    this.$modal = $('#modal');
    return this;
}
// bad
Foo.prototype.submitModal = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.doAjaxSubmit()
        .done(function() {
                // undefined function
                setTimeout(self.$modal.modal.bind(self, 'hide'), 1000)
        })
}

// good
Foo.prototype.submitModal = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.doAjaxSubmit()
        .done(function() {
            // works
            setTimeout(hideModal, 1000)
        })

    function hideModal() {
        self.$modal.modal('hide');
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in `setTimeout(self.$modal.modal.bind(self, 'hide')), 1000)`. Is this just a typo in the post or in your actual code? Or did you somehow reduce your actual code and are missing a crucial bit?

Comment: Just a typo in my post.

Comment: Why are you finding the modal function to self? that doesn't seem right. Are you sure it shouldn't be the $modal? It sounds like you want to use a partial instead of a bind. To do this, pass in undefined as the first argument of the bind function.

Comment: What is a partial?

Comment: `self.$modal.modal('hide');` is equivalent to `self.$modal.modal.call(self.$modal, 'hide');` So I guess you want `self.$modal.modal.bind(self.$modal, 'hide')` instead.

Comment: A partial (short for partial application) is where you create a new function where you seal off the first few arguments of the function (the context is preserved). If z(x, y) = x + y, then we can form a new function w(y) by sealing off the first parameter with x = 4. i.e. w(y) = z(4, y). This is what you are trying to do with the bind call: create a function whose first parameter is sealed off with the value 'hide', but you are also changing the context that the function is executed in.